Are there any philosophers who argued for a hedonistic way of living?
By hedonism I mean the pursuit of primarily pleasure, specifically carnal pleasures such as food/sex/adrenaline inducing activities/etc. It seems almost non traditional to even admit to want your life to revolve around pleasure so I wonder which philosophers if any have written about this in depth.

Epicurus is often conflated with hedonism. Though admittedly the actual facts are more subtle

None that I know of, not in any simple way.  Why do you ask?
